# Как убрать отсутствующие товары с витрины?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Пользуюсь онлайн магазином на WooCommerce, товаров **очень** много (20.000+).
Хотелось бы убрать с витрины товары которых **нет** в наличии, но они отображаются в количестве "0", однако, к сожалению, я никак не могу понять, как это реализовать.

Стоит функция "Управлять остатками".

Нарыл вот такой вот код:

```
<?php
/**
* set the stock status for all products in your WooCommerce store
* return void
*/
function woocommerce_update_stock_status(){
  global $wpdb;
  // set all status for products with 0 or less stocked quantity
  $sql = "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta stock, (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_value < 1 ) id SET stock.meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE stock.post_id = id.post_id AND stock.meta_key = '_stock_status';";
  // set all status for products with stock.
  $sql .= "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta stock, (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_value > 0 ) id SET stock.meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE stock.post_id = id.post_id AND stock.meta_key = '_stock_status';";
  // run queries
  $wpdb->query( $sql );
}
```

Что с ним делать и для чего он?

Comment: я бы искал запрос каторым эти товары выбирает из базы, и дописал там условие AND  AND meta_value > 0, или в шаблоне при выводе уже не показывать на сколько я понял сток вам прикодит